# How can I load a view of the controller constructor in a method in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to CI and am trying to redirect a user to a view, with my own data, from a method inside a controller, like so:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function doLogin() {
        extract($_POST);
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            exit;
        }
        else {
            if ($this->welcome_model->loginuser($email,$password)==true) {
                header("Location: ".base_url()."explore");
            }
            else {
                $data['errors'][] = "Email and password do not match.";
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('welcome',$data);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the lower part is supposed to load /welcome,
but instead loads /welcome/doLogin

Is there a way to load the view like the constructor? so it will load /welcome only?

Comment: Remove return true and Try again.

Comment: Just some hints: If you happen to use a framework like CI, use the methods for redirecting as well - so instead of `header()`, consider using [`redirect()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html). Additionally, no return statement needed here (the function exits, redirects or loads a view). Concerning your question, what is the other code of your controller? Maybe put it to https://pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks, didn't know redirect() existed in CI. Removing return true didnt help though.

Comment: remove `return true`

And

use public function index()

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using `welcome/doLogin` to load view and you want that how to load `(view) / doLogin` by just visiting `welcome` .

**To do so,**

```
public function index(){
     $this->doLogin();
}
```

---

By using this funtion. Whenever you will open welcome page it will redirect you to `doLogin()` function automatically.